# Is Truffle test useful?

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

Hi there I came across "Truffle test". As a developer I feel like it's better to test code on remix for unit testing rather than wasting time on writing truffle test in javascript. What do you guys think??? Is there any greater benefit of Truffle test that I'm overlooking or it's just subjective?

Comment: I think you're a QA guy, since a developer would never say something like "why waste time on writing automated tests when I can do everything manually"!

Comment: https://devqa.io/why-automate-a-test/